# How Change laravel public_path

Tags: laravel

I changed my laravel installation folder structure by moving all files and folders from the root directory to a new folder 'core'.

The goal is, to have only the folders in the root directory of the project

```
core
public
```

I have updated the index.php in public folder but I have the following problem:
when I die dump the paths, all are correct except the public path

```
dd(app_path()); //  somepath\project\core\app
dd(storage_path()); //  somepath\project\core\storage
dd(base_path()); //  somepath\project\core
dd(public_path()); //  somepath\project\core\public
```

I want to retain all other paths and change only the public path to `somepath\project\public` instead of `somepath\project\core\public` , how can I do this, online docs I've reference focus on changing public_html to public but I don't want to change the public_html, just to tell laravel that the public path is `somepath\project\public`

This particularly needful for me as I use the laravel storage for handling uploads.

Below is my folder structure

```
project
    |-core
      |- every other folders and files
    |-public
      |-every other asset files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the base path in the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` like so:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function () {
        return dirname(getcwd(), 1) . '/public';
    });
}
```

Comment: In Laravel 10, there is a new option to do this:


`app()->usePublicPath(__DIR__.'/public');`



See the upgrade doc as well: 
[https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#public-path-binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/upgrade#public-path-binding)